Spring Boot multi-user
I’m trying to create a Spring Boot application that should be able to handle the login of multiple users at the same time. The problem is that, after I login with a user on a computer, and then I login with another user on a different computer, when I refresh the dashboard an the first computer, it shows the dashboard of the second user.
I tried to search online but the only thing I found was Spring Boot session management (for single user).
This is my Security controller:

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableMethodSecurity
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class Config {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthFilter authFilter;
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) throws Exception { 
        return http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                auth.requestMatchers("/", "/**", "/auth/**", "/auth/").permitAll();
                auth.requestMatchers("/hello", "/data/dashboard").authenticated();
                /*auth.requestMatchers("/auth/hello", "/auth/hi").authenticated()
                auth.requestMatchers("/auth/workingpage").hasRole("ABCS")
            */})
            /*.formLogin(login -> login.loginPage("/auth/login.html")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/auth/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/hello", true)
                    .failureForwardUrl("/auth/registration.html")
            )*/
            .httpBasic(withDefaults()).csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .sessionManagement((session) -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(authFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception { 
        return config.getAuthenticationManager(); 
    } 

}

This code only allows single-user login

I doubt it is the spring security configuration that is at fault, but probably your custom filter or some other code in your project that is keeping state where it shouldnt'.

@M.Deinum the only modules in my project (https://github.com/BaronCode/StageProject/tree/main/src/main/java/com/stage/stageProject) that manage the authentication are Auth and Security. Can you give it a look?

Your UserController is wrong and a security leak. You are storing the token in a singleton. Don't. Why is there a logout, spring security already handles the logout? Why do you inject a controller into another controller? The @FormParam is useless in a Spring MVC application. And this is only scratching the surface...

Have you checked that the two users each have their own token? And that each request sends the correct token in the Authorization header?

@M.Deinum at the moment I don’t care about security, the problem at the top of my todo list is the multi-user

The security problem is your problem. The fact that you store the token in a singleton leads to users seeing eachothers data. Last one to login will be always the active user for everyone connected. So fix your controller and your application will work.

@M.Deinum so I tried removing the token from the controller and I found out why I added it in the first place: the web application does not send back any Authorisation header. I tried adding a CorsConfiguration I saw here on SO, but it didn’t work. I am testing on my home network.

Then fix your web application. Storing it in your controller or any place is not the solution.

@M.Deinum I tried to fix it and now I receive the authorization header when making a POST request from Postman, but no auth header is shown in JwtAuthFilter#doFilterInternal, line 31, when debugging
TL;DR Bearer token shown in Postman but not in backend
https://github.com/BaronCode/StageProject/tree/login_rev/src/main/java/com/stage/stageProject

Then you aren't sending the header (or named it wrongly).
